# Is it posible to do app for SharePoint that create another site and create a list and libraries on this other site?

Tags: sharepoint, ms-office, sharepoint-2013, sharepoint-apps, spweb

I want to create my first SharePoint App. I am wondering, is it possible to create an app which will create SharePoint site and will build a structure (with a few lists and libraries) on this site?

Answer (score 0):

Yes is possible. It depends what are your business requirements. I mean based on what rules you want to create the site (SPWeb)? Most likely you would need to create a WebPart (which is similar to a UserControl ASCX in ASP.NET) and put there the interaction with user. Then, if the sites to be created has usually the same lists and libraries and so on I would suggest you to create a Web template which contains these things and then simply create a Site based on that web template...
I can provide you some further examples if you want...

Comment: I think the OP is asking about SharePoint Apps and not Farm Solutions.

Comment: Yes I want to create SPWeb using SharePoint App not a farm Solution. I want to try replace a sandbox solution that I made for a customer with an SharePoint App that will create a structure (list and libraries) on a SPWeb that this app will create or on a host web for this app. If you can give me some samples it would be great!